# Is it possible to check if a type has been merged an inner type?

Tags: typescript

I want to check if there is a merged inner type to another type so I tried:

```js
type A = {
  field: number
}

namespace A {
  type B = {
    field: string
  }
}

type C = {
   field: boolean
}

// What should I write here?
type HasInnerB<T> = /* ??? */ ? true : false

type AHasInnerB = HasInnerB<A>; // Expected to be true since type A.B exists
type CHasInnerB = HasInnerB<C>; // Expected to be false since type C.B doesn't exist
```

I'm not sure if this is doable.

Comment: Generic type aliases take *type* arguments, not *value/expression* arguments or *namespace* arguments. So `HasInnerB<A>` can only possibly refer to the *type* named `A`, which has no `B` in it.  You can write `HasInnerB<typeof A>`, but this only refers to the *value* named `A`, which doesn't even exist unless you export variables from that namespace, and wouldn't have access to the type named `B` either. As far as I now there is absolutely no way to refer to the namespace which has types on it.  I will look to see if I can find an authoritative source on this

Comment: (see prev comment) I think this can safely be called a missing/unavailable feature. You'd need something like [ms/TS#17588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17588) or [ms/TS#55521](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55521), both of which would be a pretty big lift to implement and therefore unlikely to be part of the language anytime soon.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does that mean the `type A` and `namespace A` are different and generics only takes the `type` version?

Comment: A detailed explanation is welcome.

Comment: I will write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. A declaration in TypeScript introduces either [a named *type*, a named *value*, or a named *namespace*, or some combination of those](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts).  And the names of types, values, and namespaces don't really have anything intrinsic to do with each other.  You can't access one from the other merely because they share a name. Indeed, you can have a type named `X`, a value named `X`, and a namespace named `X`, none of which are related in any programmatic way:

```
// a namespace named X which exports a type named N
namespace X {
  export type N = { n: string };
}
const a: X.N = { n: "" }

// a value named X
const X = { v: "" };
X.v.toUpperCase();

// a type named X
type X = { t: string };
const b: X = { t: "" };
```

So it's like namespaces, values, and types live in parallel worlds.  Some declarations will introduce multiple of these with the same name, (so a `class` declaration introduces both a constructor *value* and an instance *type*; and a `namespace` declaration can introduce both a type-exporting *namespace* and a variable-exporting *value*) but you still can't access one from the other merely by virtue of their names.

And note well that this is *not* considered [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). A type named `X` and a value named `X` are not merged into a single thing.  Declararation merging can only occur when multiple declarations both introduce entities of the same name in the same world (so two *values* named `X`, or two *types* named `X`, or two *namespaces* named `X`)... and only some merges are actually allowed (you can't generally merge two values together, or two type aliases, etc).

---

It's not clear from the question in what sense you want to check an arbitrary entity for a member named `B`, since this has three different meanings depending on which world the entity lives in.  But currently, TypeScript only provides [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type* parameters and arguments.  Any utility of the form `HasInnerB<T>` requires `T` to be a *type*, not a value.

So if you write `HasInnerB<A>`, that `A` has nothing to do with the namespace named `A` which exports a type named `B`.  So no matter how you implement `HasInnerB<T>` it's not going to work as desired.

---

In order to begin for this to be possible, TypeScript would have to add features that let you abstract over values and namespaces.  Right now there's absolutely nothing like this for namespaces, and for values the [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) can only act on a value directly, not on some "value parameter" (so you can write `typeof val` but there is no way to write `type TypeOf<T> = typeof T` since that `T` is a type parameter, not a value parameter).

It's possible that some feature request like [microsoft/TypeScript#17588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17588) or [microsoft/TypeScript#55521](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55521) or [microsoft/TypeScript#56124](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56124) would give us the ability to write `HasInnerB<T>` if implemented, but this would probably be a large undertaking (it's not the basic feature that's hard, but dealing with how it interacts with the rest of the language that is the tricky part) and I don't see much enthusiasm for such features in GitHub (the most upvoted of those features has 54  as of 2024-01-10, which isn't negligible but far from what would be needed to be considered popular) so I very much doubt this will happen anytime soon, unfortunately.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.3.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAUEpEAeMA9gE4AuSpAnjMgHJIC8GSwAXElKcQJbADmSAL4BubEgD043ARLl4hYJySVGSAIyjBmeYvIh2KAHT0m6FuwBEFoZm0KlaU0gBul6yMxHnh0oQCqMDTEAMIgUBAAFACUophUNKiqZqTsnDz8QqI6SgBGBkkUbpm2tkA)